# How to change shape of opencv detected scale

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, haar-classifier

My problem is the width and height of rectangle are equals and I want to change it to rectangle not square (width and height are different)
[image: image sample]
and this is my code

```
img = cv2.imread(pic)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
coils,reject,level = coil_cascade.detectMultiScale3(gray,1.3,5, outputRejectLevels=True)
for (x,y,w,h) in coils:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Quick and not useful solution is `cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w+20,y+h),(255,0,0),2)` or `y+h+20` based on do you want it one way or another. Just to make it uneven.

Comment: thanks for solution but I want it naturally detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you train it with squares it will of course output squares. There is only one scale factor for both dimensions.

To change that either train it with the desired aspect ratio or change the rectangles befor drawing them.